# Connect two remote oracle databases as a schemas on each other

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, database-link

This Question is about Oracle Database.

I have two remote databases DB_1 and DB_2, and I have two schemas on each database:
Schema DB_1 and Schema DB_2 on database DB_1, and Schema DB_1 and Schema DB_2 on database DB_2.
I want to reach database DB_2 Schema DB_2 from database DB_1 Schema DB_1.
For example: when I try this query  in DB_1 from  schema DB_1:

`SELECT * FROM DB_2.example_table`

I got an error because there is not table "example_table" in DB_2 Schema on the DB_1 database.
But, when I try the same query on DB_2 Schema DB_2, I got the correct result (some data).

So, I need to tune my databases in some way so I can `SELECT * FROM DB_2.example_TABLE` from DB_1 Database.

But, there is another problem, I don't have permission to `CREATE LINK`.
However, when I query `SELECT * FROM ALL_LINKS;` on my production database DB_1 schema DB_1 - there are no links at all. So, I need to figure out which way my production Databases was linked (unfortunately my colleagues don't know either). On my production database DB_1 schema DB_1 I can fetch data with the query:

`SELECT * FROM DB_2.example_table`

And the data I got is the same if I try to query the same on DB_2 production database DB_2 schema.

But there are no public\private Links on DB1/DB2 production databases at all. Is there another way to create a "connect" between my databases? (I queried `SELECT * FROM ALL_LINKS` from DB_1 schema DB_1, is this possible so I can fetch some other data if I try the query on DB_1 schema DB_2?)

**Thanks in anticipation!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues, in no particular order.

Your SELECT syntax is wrong. To select a table from another database the syntax is

```
select some_columns from remote_table@remote_db;
```

Note the "@remote_db".  Here 'remote_db' refers to an entry in the *local* database's tnsnames.ora file, which in turn resolves to the remote db in question.   ***CORRECTION:  Here 'remote_db' is the name of the database link.***

Second, you say you have no permission to create a db link. Well, someone is going to have to create one.  That *is* the mechanism by which one database queries another. Period. Full stop.

Third, you say you find no db links when you query ALL_LINKS.  The name of the view is ALL_DB_LINKS.  And *that* only shows the links that the current user has permissions on.  If you want to see all links in the database, you query DBA_DB_LINKS, as a user that has permissions to query that view.  Plus, I see nothing in your question description that would cause me to suspect that there indeed *are* any db links.

Comment: Hello Ed, Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful.